# How can I remove a certain pattern from a string?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this string like `"682_2, 682_3, 682_4"`. (682 is a random number)

How can i get this string `"2, 3, 4"` using regex and ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in ruby

```rb
input="682_2, 682_3, 682_4"
output = input.gsub(/\d+_/,"")
puts output
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex could be

`/_([0-9]+)$/` and in the match group of the result you will have 2 for 682_2 and 3 for 682_3

Ruby code snippet would be `"64532_2".match(/_([0-9]+)/).captures[0]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `scan` which returns an array containing the matches:

```
string_code.scan(/(?<=_)\d/)
```

`(?<=_)` tells to find a pattern that has a given pattern (`_` in this case) before itself but wont capture that, it captures only `\d`. if it can have more than 1 digit like `682_13,682_33` then `\d+` is necessary.